# What is the difference between apiserver-kubelet-client, apiserver and kubelet certificates

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, private-key, pki

I am getting confused with all the certificates and keys in Kubernetes.

Inside the master I have the following certificates and keys:

```
/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt
/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key

/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key

/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.crt
/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.key
```

The `apiserver-kubelet-client (crt\key)` is used for secure communication between the apiserver and the kubelet inside the Master.
Why I have also the `kubelet (crt\key)`? Isn't the `apiserver-kubelet-client (crt\key)` is enough ?

Why I need `apiserver (crt\key)` if I have `apiserver-kubelet-client (crt\key)`  ?

Hope someone can make some order with this.

I read [this](https://jvns.ca/blog/2017/08/05/how-kubernetes-certificates-work) article about Kubernetes PKI but I am still don't understand what is difference between the above certificates and keys.

Comment: Afaik, Both of these components use different certificates and keys to communicate with each other.  Both of these components behave sometimes Server and sometime clients. When ApiServer communicate with Kublet It behave as a client and viceversa.

Answer (score 1):

I was also asking my self similar question.

The first thing u need to know is that both the kubelet and the api-server communicate with each other [0].

The second thing is that Kubernetes uses client certificates to authenticate a client identity to the server and a server certificate to authenticate the server’s identity to the client and establish an encrypted connection .

In case of `kubelet -> api-server` kubelet needs a client certificate and api-server a server certificate and for `api-server -> kubelet` then the otherway around.

you can check if a certificate is a server or client one using:

```
openssl x509  -noout -text -in apiserver.crt
```

Now back to the question :

- `/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt` and `/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.crt` are server certificates
- `/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt` and `/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem` are client certificates

0. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/control-plane-node-communication/

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/#kubelet-serving-certs seems to suggest that the `/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.crt` is self-signed. Any idea how it is that the kube-apiserver is able to securely(TLS) connect to the kubelet (acting as the server)?

Answer (score 0):

While preparing certs, you will end up with at least 1 file.

- CA_CERT

  - put in on node where apiserver runs, for example in /srv/kubernetes/ca.crt.
- MASTER_CERT

  - signed by CA_CERT
  - put in on node where apiserver runs, for example in /srv/kubernetes/server.crt
- MASTER_KEY

  - put in on node where apiserver runs, for example in /srv/kubernetes/server.key

You can read about it in Kubernetes docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/scratch#preparing-certs).

It’s hard to say by the names of your certs what are they used for.
You should refer to the standard configuration.
Besides, you can have a look at [kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/04-certificate-authority.md) as he’s showing how and when to use certificates.

You can check this [comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/54665#issuecomment-340908025) posted on Github regarding what kind of certifications are needed between which services.